# what's the difference between (*iter)->method() and (*iter).method()?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
vector<Object*>::iterator iter;

for(iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
{
    (*iter)->methodA(); 
}
```

I know (*iter)->methodA(); is equivalent to (*(*iter)).methodA();

but I don't understand why we need a second *. Shouldn't *iter point to the value (pointer value or address of an instance of Object) of iter, which is an address (iter pointing to the address of itself). Pointers are very confusing.

Comment: One would compile, the other one won't, since `(*iter)` doesn't evaluate to a reference to `Object`.

Comment: if `(iter)->methodA();` is equivalent to `(*iter).methodA()`, than `(*iter)->methodA();` must be equivalent to `(**iter).methodA()`

Comment: A pointer is no object (An instance of some size representing all data members) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*iter)` gets the contents of the iterator. And since the contents of `vector<Object*>` are pointers themselves, you need the `->` to get at `methodA`.

Comment: So, because the pointers by themselves are useless and we need the objects, which the pointers point to, we use a second *? Gotcha.

Comment: no, pointers are not useless, but since you want an object you dereference pointer

Comment: @user3435009 Look up some examples of using iterators for `vectors` that don't contain pointers. The `(*itr)` is how you get what the iterator itself points to. Once you have that you have to deal with it appropriately. In your case you get a pointer out of the iterator hence the `->`.

Answer (score 3):

`*iter` gives you an `Object*`. This is a pointer, so you need to use `->` or a further `*` to call methods through it. It is the same as

```
Object* p = *iter;
p->methodA();
(*p).methodA();
```

As for your question title, `(*iter).methodA()` shouldn't compile.

Comment: it's confusing, because in your example you use it only once, so is it because iter is itself a pointer or something?

Comment: @user3435009 `iter` is an iterator. It kind of models a pointer, but it isn't one. It has de-reference operators `->` and `*` to make it look like a pointer. Note that a pointer *is* an iterator though.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator is an abstraction. This is a concept, and anything that behaves like iterator is iterator. This is why you can here a statement that *a pointer is an iterator*.

[Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator)

For type **It** to be an Iterator, in addition to the other requirements, the following conditions have to be satisfied for an object **i** of such type:

```
Expression  Return    Precondition
*i        reference   i is dereferenceable [2]
++i           It&
```

So assuming iterator

```
vector<Object*>::iterator iter;
```

then:

```
   (*iter) -> methodA();
   ^^^^^^^  ^       
&(Object*)  dereference pointer and call methodA on the object
                                         pointed to by pointer

   (*iter) . methodA();
   ^^^^^^^  ^       
&(Object*)  call methodA on the pointer? error: request for member ‘methodA’ in 
           ‘it.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* 
           [with _Iterator = Object**, _Container = std::vector<Object*, 
           std::allocator<Object*> >]()’, which is of non-class type ‘Object*’
           make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```